# You probably tried to upload too large file. even when i change php.ini

Tags: php, database

I am trying to import a sql file in my database , but I get this errors

```
You probably tried to upload too large file.
```

I changed in php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize=500M
```

and I still have the same errors , Size of the sql file is 500Mo

What I should add to make it working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to also increase the post_max_size value in your php.ini

Answer (score 4):

What is `Mo` for ?  Just add `upload_max_filesize = 500M` and don't forget to save your PHP.ini and do a restart of the webserver.

Comment: Just a error when I wrote it , I have upload_max_filesize = 500M in my php.ini , I restart all services 
but when I try o import  I have : (Maximum size: 8 192Kio) . Where is the problem ?

Comment: @HappyGeekette Kio isn't a size, either.

Comment: @Daedalus I just copied what it is writen , Thank's any way